# Group By Jalali Date in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I want `GROUP BY` jalali's month, all date save as gregorian format in my database, I found following sql query but group by gregorian date

```
SELECT COUNT(reserverow.id), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reserverow.used_date) as "Month"
FROM reserverow
WHERE reserverow.used_date > '2000-09-28 01:00:00'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reserverow.used_date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [Team Appir's `jalali_utils` extension for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/teamappir/jalali_utils). Then you could write your query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(reserverow.id), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reserverow.used_date) as "Month"
  FROM reserverow
 WHERE reserverow.used_date > '2000-09-28 01:00:00'
 GROUP BY JALALI_PART('month', reserverow.used_date)
```